# Turn off Joomla System Session at the front end

Tags: caching, joomla

I have a popular joomla site(4000/day) at shared server. I have performance problems. I want to disable joomla system session at frontend, so I take this row to the index.php:

```
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site',array('session'=>false));
```

It works well for guests, but have a side effect. It is really strange, but when I logged in as registered user and turn on the debug mode, I experience that joomla module caching isn't work.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Cache will not work if debug mode is on.

Comment: So if I in debug mode and I am a guest cache will work, but if I logged in, cache will not work in debug mode?

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for disabling session in 3.X?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is to turn sessions back on for logged in users.

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->guest) {
  $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site',array('session'=>false));
}
```

Comment: Thanks the good idea, but I realized, that Joomla Cache doesn't work when the user is logged in. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you talking about module caching or page caching? Module caching works whether a user is a guest or logged in. Page caching only works on guest users. That is how the core works, you would have to hack the core in order to change the behavior. Read this - http://www.theartofjoomla.com/joomla-caching-explained.html

Comment: It would seem like you need to turn on Page caching as well as module caching and leave sessions alone. If you still have performance issues then you should consider getting better hosting.

Comment: Thanks your help! I use module caching, but it seems doesn't work when user logged in. I turned on the debug mode, so you can see it with your eyes. URL: http://www.valovilag4.com/  name: sam   psw:123456

Comment: It looks like Gaurav has your answer above. It would make sense to turn off caching when you are trying to debug.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code in the core joomla plugin - plugin/system/cache.php, you will see that it will only cache non authenticated user pages, you could change to allow for logged in user pages to be cached, but this could have adverse side effects, ie all users seeing the last logged in persons cached page, which could contain sensitive information.

A more custom caching solution would be required  to prevent this sort of thing happening